# PHP is_float() validation

Tags: php

I need to (check) if my input is float but I cannot get it to work.

```
    $input_number = trim($_POST['number']);
    if(empty($input_number)){
        $input_number_err = 'an error msg';
    } elseif(is_float($input_number)){
        $number = $input_number;
    } else{
        $input_number_err = 'an error msg';
    }
```

I also tried to add 0 inside my if statement but nothing changed

```
elseif(is_float($input_number + 0))
```

Comment: The input values I am providing (10.50 , 10.5) . Both dont work

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what does that mean? At no point in the above code do you output anything to see if it worked? (and this would work with `+0`)

Comment: I mean that it doesnt rerurn true as it should. I know that +0 should work but it doesnt in the code I posted.

Comment: The above code definitely does work with `+0` (assuming that your `$_POST["number"]` is a string); you should `var_dump` your `$_POST` and see what that actually shows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of [`floatval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) here, to convert your string to a float, if possible.

As an example:

```php
$input_number = trim($_POST['number']);
if (empty($input_number)) {
  $input_number_err = 'an error msg';
}
elseif (floatval($input_number)) {
  $number = $input_number;
}
else {
  $input_number_err = 'an error msg';
}

// Feedback
if (isset($number)) {
  echo 'Your float is: ' . $number;
}
elseif (isset($input_number_err)) {
  echo 'Your input is not a float: ' . $input_number_err;
}
```

Comment: `floatval` isn't the best solution here because it will cause unexpected behaviour in some situations (e.g. `floatval("randomString") === 0.0`); also `0.0 == false` but potentially is a valid input? It seems `is_numeric` would be the better choice